# WPF EF Core depencency injection with generic pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

currently I'm experimenting with WPF/EFCore and DI. I already set up the `Application` class to register the different/upcoming services like this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private IHost AppHost;

    public App()
    {
        AppHost = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices((context, services) => 
                {
                    ConfigureServices(context.Configuration, services);
                })
                .Build();
    }

    private void ConfigureServices(IConfiguration Configuration, IServiceCollection Services)
    {
        Services.AddDbContext<AppDataContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ProdToolDb"));
        });

        Services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();
    }


    protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        await AppHost.StartAsync();

        MainWindow MainWindow = AppHost.Services.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();
        MainWindow.Show();

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }


    protected override async void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        using (AppHost)
        {
            await AppHost.StopAsync();
        }
        base.OnExit(e);
    }

}
```

Of course, I have the appr. `DataContext` classes too:

```
public class AppDataContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDataContext(DbContextOptions<AppDataContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Capacity> Capacities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CapacityType> CapacityTypes { get; set; }
}

public class AppDataContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<AppDataContext>
{
    public AppDataContext CreateDbContext(string[] args = null)
    {
        DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDataContext> OptionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDataContext>();
        IConfigurationRoot Config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

        OptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Config.GetConnectionString("ProdToolDb"));

        return new AppDataContext(OptionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

I was told in an other question, that in order to get the migration working with EF Core, I have to use `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`.

Now, going further, I set up the generic pattern implementation. I created an interface:

```
public interface IDataService<T>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll();

    Task<T> Get(int Id);

    Task<T> Create(T Entity);

    Task<T> Update(int Id, T Entity);

    Task<bool> Delete(int Id);
}
```

and it's implementation:

```
public class GenericDataService<T> : IDataService<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly AppDataContextFactory ContextFactory;

    public GenericDataService(AppDataContextFactory contextFactory)
    {
        ContextFactory = contextFactory;
    }

    public async Task<T> Create(T Entity)
    {
        using (AppDataContext Context = ContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            await Context.Set<T>().AddAsync(Entity);
            await Context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Entity;
        }
    }

    ... other methods omitted for brevity
}
```

I have the following questions:

1. Since I use `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` in order to have created and configured the `DataContext`, is this call in the startup redundant?

   ```
        Services.AddDbContext<AppDataContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ProdToolDb"));
        });
   ```

Or should I instead of this create a `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` service and register it? If yes, then how?

2. As you see in the `IDataService` implementation, I use `AppDataContextFactory` and `AppDataContext` directly, not with the DI technique. How should I modify the code in order to use DI?
3. And if I would like to handle everything above with DI, I have to register/add `GenericDataService<T>` in the startup class, right? How can I do that?

Please advise.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I read the linked blog entries and others too and now I see, why you say, that the generic pattern is an antipattern. I will throw it away and concentrate on the general WPF binding methods and DI of views/viewmodels.

Comment: The easy part is that you don't need any kind of "generic" repository or pattern, that's what EF Core itself provides. In fact, that "generic" repository is a well known **antipattern**. That `Create` method can easily perform 100 UPDATEs, 20 DELETEs and 5 INSERTs

Comment: First of all, DbSet is *already* a repository (says so in the docs), a DbContext is already a Unit-of-Work. A DbContext is neither a database connection nor a model of the database. It's meant to contain and manage the entities in a single bounded context (in DDD terms) or single scenario.  It already works in a disconnected mode (which is a **very** good thing). It caches all changes and only persists them when `SaveChanges` is called. It's a higher-level abstraction when the CRUD-like repository is a low-level construct.

Comment: Consider this: Why did you add that `IDataService`? What *real* problem did you face? Or did you add it because someone, somewhere, wrote it's a "best practice"? It may have been 15 years ago, before ORMs like NHibernate and Entity Framework came about. Since 2009 at least though, it's bad practice - the ORMs provide the data layer abstraction *and* the unit testing endpoints

Comment: Check Oren Eini's [Repository is the new Singleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton) from 2009. At the time, Oren Eini was the maintainer of NHibernate. Also check Gunnar Peipman's [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) which explains why the generic repository is so bad, and why `Create` performs 100 DELETEs

Comment: `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` isn't needed either. Whatever it does can be done in `AddDbContext`, where you still have access to `IConfiguration`. This makes `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` redundant, not `AddDbContext` - if you wanted to change the connection string eg based on command-line arguments, the best place would be in `AddDbContext`.

Comment: I (also) don't find a generic layer on top of entity framework terribly useful. A layer which returns specific typed lists etc can be useful in automated testing.

Comment: If you're going to use DI with WPF you might want to consider if the microsoft one is well suited to your requirements. I prefer alternatives such as ninject for desktop apps.